# How to remove random part of string in javascript imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have some strings

> "D:\trial\img\2\5-trendy-high-heel-oxford-shoes.jpg"
>
> "D:\trial\img\3\20-cute-heels-street-style_01.jpg"
>
> "D:\trial\img\4\637d3c5673d97326f9517ad24ba99e76.jpg"
>
> "D:\trial\img\5\126003_P_1388122701631.jpg"

I wants to remove "`D:\trial\img\2\`" and wants only "`5-trendy-high-heel-oxford-shoes.jpg`"

But as you can see all string have different number after sub string `img`.

Please help me to fix this for imacros javascript eval feature.

here is my imacros code

```
SET !DATASOURCE D:\trial\ima_kuwot.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 50
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !VAR1 {{!COL3}}
Add !EXTRACT "D:\trial\img\3\20-cute-heels-street-style_01.jpg"
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split('img\')[2];")
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");") 
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!VAR1}}\"; s.replace(/[]+/g,'.jpg')")
SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!VAR1}}'.split('D:"\trial\img\1\"')[0].trim();")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SEARCH ATTR=ID:media-search-input CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

I tried above eval statements but nothing working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, the following syntax works:

```
SET !EXTRACT D:\\\trial\\\img\\\3\\\5-trendy-high-heel-oxford-shoes.jpg
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/[\d\w\-\.]+$/);")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

(At least in 'iMacros for Firefox' and 'iMacros for Chrome'.)

Comment: thank you so much but as i can see i have to add extra back slashes

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are extracting these path strings from a webpage. I don't think you will be able to use the iMacros EVAL command to parse out the file names, because the backslash characters are treated as escape characters when stuffing the extracted path into the string that makes up the EVAL command.

For example, let's say that you've already extracted one of the paths and it is now in the !EXTRACT variable. Attempting to use this variable in the EVAL command as follows will not work:

```
SET fullPath EVAL("var path = '{{!EXTRACT}}'; path;")
PROMPT {{fullPath}}
```

The value of fullPath will not be what is expected because the backslash characters in the extracted text are treated as escape characters.

In order to do this properly, you will need to make use of the Javascript scripting interface, assuming that you are using iMacros for Firefox. In this case, you will play a Javascript (.js) script that will then play a macro for extracting the paths, and then the extracted values will be returned to the script code via the iimGetExtract call where the file names can be parsed out using a regular expression.

I created an example macro that enters a couple of the path values provided into a form field and then extracts them back out, along with the corresponding Javascript to process the values.

**ExtractFilePaths.iim:**

```
URL GOTO=http://demo.imacros.net/Automate/TestForm1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:name CONTENT=D:\trial\img\2\5-trendy-high-heel-oxford-shoes.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:name EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:name CONTENT=D:\trial\img\3\20-cute-heels-street-style_01.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:name EXTRACT=TXT
```

**GetFileNames.js:**

```
iimPlay("ExtractFilePaths");

var regex = /D:\\trial\\img\\\d+\\(.*)/i;
var noMatch = "Match not found";
var fileName;
var matches;

matches = regex.exec(iimGetExtract(1));
fileName = matches ? matches[1] : noMatch;
alert(fileName);

matches = regex.exec(iimGetExtract(2));
fileName = matches ? matches[1] : noMatch;
alert(fileName);
```

For more information about using the Javascript scripting interface in iMacros for Firefox, see the following:

http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface

Comment: can we use var regex = /D:\\trial\\img\\\d+\\(.*)/i; in imacros .iim interface with eval feature ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as I explained in my answer, the reason why this will not work with EVAL in an .iim macro is because the the backslash characters \ in the extracted path values are interpreted as escape characters by the EVAL command.

Comment: Since I cannot yet comment on other's answers, I will comment here with regard to the chosen answer. My answer was crafted specifically under the assumption that the path values are being extracted from a web page, since the original version of the question did not explicitly mention the source of those values. I stand behind my answer for this scenario.

The answer provided by Shugar is certainly viable for cases where the user has direct control over the value of the paths.